# Grep particular values from file and assign it to a variables

Tags: shell

Below is the file

```
TMPQM>CSQN205I   COUNT=     213, RETURN=00000000, REASON=00000000
CSQM401I ?TMPQM
QUEUE(Q1)                     TYPE(QLOCAL)
QSGDISP(QMGR)             CURDEPTH(0)
CSQM401I ?TMPQM
QUEUE(Q2)                     TYPE(QLOCAL)
QSGDISP(QMGR)             CURDEPTH(23)
CSQM401I ?TMPQM
QUEUE(Q3)               TYPE(QLOCAL)
QSGDISP(QMGR)             CURDEPTH(150)
CSQM401I ?TMPQM
```

My intention is to get the values,

```
Q=Q1
V=0

Q=Q2
V=23

Q=Q3
V=150
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need all those messy `<br/>` tags, either!

Comment: you're reassignment to Q will wipe out the previous values. So now assuming you really need to read each of these values for Q and process with them the question is a lot more complicated..... How to maintain through each pass of a file which Q, Q1, Q2, Q3, you're going to process? Good luck.

Comment: I'm printing the Q value on stdout on every new assignment. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use bash?  Not the most efficient, but here's a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

count=1
for queue in `grep "QUEUE" input.txt`
do
    # Strip the beginning up to (
    q1="${queue#*(}"
    # Strip the end from ) on
    q2="${q1%%)*}"
    q[$count]=$q2
    count=$((count+1))
done

count=1
for value in `grep "CURDEPTH" input.txt`
do
    # Strip the beginning up to (
    v1="${value##*(}"
    # Strip the end from ) on
    v2="${v1%)*}"
    v[$count]=$v2
    count=$((count+1))
done

for index in 1 2 3
do
    echo "Q=${q[$index]}"
    echo "V=${v[$index]}"
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

The fancy for loops are just to deal with looping through lines with spaces in bash.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of pcregrep and sed will do the job. pcregrep supports multiline matches with the -M option

```
-bash-3.2$ pcregrep -M -o '^QUEUE[(](.+?)[)].*\n.*CURDEPTH[(](\d+?)[)]$' trial.txt | sed -e 's/^QUEUE(\([^)]\+\)).*$/Q=\1/g' -e 's/.*CURDEPTH(\([^)]\+\))/V=\1/g'  
Q=Q1
V=0
Q=Q2
V=23
Q=Q3
V=150
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
grep -oP '(?<=QUEUE|CURDEPTH)\S+' input.txt | tr -d '()' | (while read NAME && read VAL; do echo $NAME=$VAL; done)
```

It's a little more flexible than @cravoori's solution because you can format the output easily. That line's output is...

```
Q1=0
Q2=23
Q3=150
```

...which you can `source` and then read directly using `$Q1`, `$Q2`, etc.